# File polling issue when a file is modified file it is not polling spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to pull file from a folder when a new file is created or modified.
As per my current code its working when new file is created, but when i am adding same file with modified contents but that is not polling.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Files.inboundAdapter(new File(FOLDER)), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10000)))
            .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
            .handle("processor", "process", e -> e.advice(advice()))
            .get();
}
@Bean
public Processor processor() {
    return new Processor();
}
@Bean
public AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice advice() {
    return new AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
            File file = message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class);
            try {
                Object result = callback.execute();
                String fileName=file.getName();
                System.out.println("new file created");
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}

 public static class Processor {

    public void process(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Files.inboundAdapter()` must be configured with the `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which check for the `lastmodified`, unlike an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` which is used by default.

See more about that in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/file.html#file-reading